# Skip part of a screenshot

Tags: python

i am trying to make an autoclicker for an offline game to kill bots by clicking on their health, but i mostly click on myself.
to solve this i need to make it that when i make a screenshot it doesnt check 900,600 to 1000,660.
i have been trying to do this for a few hours but found no solution, heres my code:

```
from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import random
import win32api, win32con

def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)

color = (0, 255, 32)

while keyboard.is_pressed('q') == False:
    s = pyautogui.screenshot()

    width, height = s.size

    for x in range(0,width,5):
        for y in range(0,height,5):
            if s.getpixel((x, y)) == color:
                
                click(x+0,y+0)
                pyautogui.keyDown('space')
                pyautogui.keyUp('space')
                time.sleep (0.05)
```

Comment: You might want to edit your question and add more specific tags. It looks like it belongs in a small nice of what Python can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    for x in range(0,width,5):
        for y in range(0,height,5):
            if (900<=x<=1000) and (600<=y<=660): continue
            if s.getpixel((x, y)) == color:
```

or with generators

```
def range_skip(start, end, step, skipStart, skipEnd):
    for n in range(start, end, step):
        if skipStart<=n<=skipEnd: continue
        yield n

# .....

    for x in range(0,width,5):
        yrange = range(0,height,5)
        if (900<=x<=1000):
            yrange = range_skip(0, height, 5, 600, 660)
        for y in yrange:
            if s.getpixel((x, y)) == color:
```

If you are sure the skip range is inside `start .. end`

You must round `skipEnd` to the `step` if being pedantic

```
def range_skip(start, end, step, skipStart, skipEnd):
    for n in range(start, skipStart, step):
        yield n
    for n in range(skipEnd, end, step):
        yield n
```